# error al cambiar cuenta de inicio de servicio en SQL SERVER: asignacion nombres de cuenta

Tags: sql-server

Os pongo en situación: Windows server 2012 R2 con SQL Server 2008 R2.

Al intentar actualizar a SQL server 2014, me aparece varias veces el error:

> "**no se efectuó ninguna asignación entre los nombres de cuenta y los identificadores de seguridad**."

Y también el error

> "value cannot be null. Parameter name: userGroupName".

No consigue hacer la actualización de los servicios de *SQL Server* ni del agente de *SQL Server*, del resto si.

[image: error al actualizar a sql server 2014]
[image: segundo error: value cannot be null usergroupname]
[[image: error cambiando cuenta de servicio para sql server o agente][2]]

A raíz de esto descubro que cuando quiero cambiar la cuenta de servicio en la herramienta de administración de *SQL Server* para el motor de *SQL* o el agente de *SQL*, me da el mismo error.

En cambio no me da ese error cuando cambio la cuenta de servicio de *SSIS*. Lo mas curioso es que da el error, pero si que llega a cambiar la cuenta de servicio y arrancar el servicio.

Este servidor empezó siendo un SQL Server 2008 que era miembro del dominio, luego pasó a ser controlador de dominio secundario (ya se que la recomendación de Microsoft es que un *SQL Server* no puede pasar a ser DC una vez instalado, pero funcionó bien).

He probado a quitarle los roles de DC, y sigue dando el mismo error. He revisado los SID de conexión con  `select * from sys.server_principals` y veo un par de cosas extrañas:

`NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER` y `NT SERVICE\MSSERVERAGENT` aparecen como `WINDOWS_GROUP`,  pero ninguna de estas cuentas me aparecen como grupo (ni como usuario en el controlador de dominio). Ni las puedo utilizar para arrancar los servicios. Imagino que al pasar el servidor a DC borra estas cuentas virtuales ya que Microsoft no permite usar cuentas virtuales o locales cuando *SQL Server* es *DC*.

```
NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT   262 0x010600000000000550000000DCA88F14B79FD47A992A3D8943F829A726066357  G   WINDOWS_GROUP   0   2011-11-02 12:45:41.867 2011-11-02 12:45:41.877 master  us_english  NULL.
```

También he probado a eliminar de la tabla `sys.server_principals` los dos *NT service*, pero sigue dándome el mismo error.

Creo que todo tiene que ver con el *SID* de las cuentas de Windows en relación a las cuentas de *SQL Server*, es como si al intentar validar esa cuenta de servicio, primero comprobara todas las cuentas disponibles y alguna diera error,  pero no veo como arreglarlo sin tener que reinstalar SQL SERVER; es un servidor de producción y no quiero llegar a este punto.

Quizás desde Regedit se pueda hacer algo, ¡pero necesito ayuda!

Resumen log de actualización:

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2147467261
  Start time:                    2020-08-08 14:25:26
  End time:                      2020-08-08 14:48:30
  Requested action:              Upgrade

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for SQLEngine:       The upgrade process for SQL Server failed. To continue the upgrade process, use the following information to resolve the error. Next, uninstall SQL Server by using this command line: setup /q /action=uninstall /instanceid=MSSQLSERVER /features=SQLENGINE,FULLTEXT,REPLICATION. Then, run SQL Server Setup again.
  Next step for FullText:        The upgrade process for SQL Server failed. To continue the upgrade process, use the following information to resolve the error. Next, uninstall SQL Server by using this command line: setup /q /action=uninstall /instanceid=MSSQLSERVER /features=SQLENGINE,FULLTEXT,REPLICATION. Then, run SQL Server Setup again.
  Next step for Replication:     The upgrade process for SQL Server failed. To continue the upgrade process, use the following information to resolve the error. Next, uninstall SQL Server by using this command line: setup /q /action=uninstall /instanceid=MSSQLSERVER /features=SQLENGINE,FULLTEXT,REPLICATION. Then, run SQL Server Setup again.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  SONTINYENT
  Machine processor count:       20
  OS version:                    Windows Server 2012
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   español (España)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured
  SQL Server 2008 R2   MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER         Database Engine Services                 1033                 Standard Edition     10.53.6000.34   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2008 R2   MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER         SQL Server Replication                   1033                 Standard Edition     10.53.6000.34   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2008 R2   MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER         Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search 1033                 Standard Edition     10.53.6000.34   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2008 R2                                                       Management Tools - Basic                 1033                 Standard Edition     10.53.6000.34   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2008 R2                                                       Management Tools - Complete              1033                 Standard Edition     10.53.6000.34   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2008 R2                                                       Client Tools Connectivity                1033                 Standard Edition     10.53.6000.34   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2008 R2                                                       Client Tools Backwards Compatibility     1033                 Standard Edition     10.53.6000.34   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2008 R2                                                       Client Tools SDK                         1033                 Standard Edition     10.53.6000.34   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2008 R2                                                       Integration Services                     1033                 Standard Edition     10.53.6000.34   No         Yes       

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2014 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2014
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       12
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         E:\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Standard

Product Update Status:
  None discovered.

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Upgrade
  AGTDOMAINGROUP:                <empty>
  ALLOWUPGRADEFORSSRSSHAREPOINTMODE: false
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20200808_142525\ConfigurationFile.ini
  ENU:                           true
  ERRORREPORTING:                false
  FAILOVERCLUSTERROLLOWNERSHIP:  2
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  FTUPGRADEOPTION:               Import
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MsDtsServer120
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  RSCATALOGSERVERINSTANCENAME:   Unknown
  RSUPGRADEDATABASEACCOUNT:      <empty>
  RSUPGRADEPASSWORD:             <empty>
  SQMREPORTING:                  false
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20200808_142525\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Management Tools - Complete
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Client Tools Connectivity
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Client Tools SDK
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Client Tools Backwards Compatibility
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Management Tools - Basic
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     The upgrade process for SQL Server failed. To continue the upgrade process, use the following information to resolve the error. Next, uninstall SQL Server by using this command line: setup /q /action=uninstall /instanceid=MSSQLSERVER /features=SQLENGINE,FULLTEXT,REPLICATION. Then, run SQL Server Setup again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          -2147467261
  Error description:             Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: userGroupName
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=0xC74B07E0%400x11428655&EvtType=0xC74B07E0%400x11428655

  Feature:                       Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     The upgrade process for SQL Server failed. To continue the upgrade process, use the following information to resolve the error. Next, uninstall SQL Server by using this command line: setup /q /action=uninstall /instanceid=MSSQLSERVER /features=SQLENGINE,FULLTEXT,REPLICATION. Then, run SQL Server Setup again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          -2147467261
  Error description:             Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: userGroupName
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=0xC74B07E0%400x11428655&EvtType=0xC74B07E0%400x11428655

  Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     The upgrade process for SQL Server failed. To continue the upgrade process, use the following information to resolve the error. Next, uninstall SQL Server by using this command line: setup /q /action=uninstall /instanceid=MSSQLSERVER /features=SQLENGINE,FULLTEXT,REPLICATION. Then, run SQL Server Setup again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          -2147467261
  Error description:             Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: userGroupName
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=0xC74B07E0%400x11428655&EvtType=0xC74B07E0%400x11428655

  Feature:                       Integration Services
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Browser
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Writer
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Setup Support Files
  Status:                        Passed

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20200808_142525\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Comment: acabo de localizar un post de una persona que tiene exactamente el mismo problema: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/02e7544d-0501-4047-a316-e4723752eae4/upgrade-from-sql-server-2008-r2-to-sql-server-2012-sp1-failure?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade    . Lo que no tengo claro es si tengo que poner en todos los servicios de SQL SERVER una cuenta de dominio con permisos, es decir, quitar cualquiera que empiece por NT AUTHORITY dentro de la herramienta de administracion de SQL SERVER, y sustituirlo por mi usuario de dominio con privilegios?

Answer (score 0):

En el artículo que encontraste dicen que el camino pasa por:

1. Borrar instancias inactivas de MSSQL 2012 y regresar a MSSQL 2008. Este paso es el que está un poco perdido porque el blog citado ya no existe (*recordatorio gratis de por qué poner enlaces en las preguntas y respuestas es pésima idea*).
2. Cambiar temporalmente cualquier cuenta en los servicios de MSSQL en el servidor (`Database Engine` account, `SQL Server Agent` account, SSAS, etc.) que estén corriendo (*Estas eran cuentas de dominio en la instalación de quien comentó*).  Quien comenta en ese post las cambió para que esos servicios usaran su cuenta de usuario (ej. AngelZuniga) -con permisos de admin- y luego las devolvió a las cuentas originales después de los cambios.
3. Correr la herramienta *SQL repair tool* de nuevo (control panel -> Desinstalar/cambiar el programa SQL Server y clic en "Reparar") y no debería haber problemas.  No resuelve nada pero ayuda a dejar MSSQL en un estado predecible.
4. Correr el upgrade a SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Gracias, hasta el sabado no puedo realizar estos cambios, ya que se trata de un servidor de producción. En cualquier caso tengo la sensación de que esto no funcionará, y digo esto porque cuando cambio la cuenta de servicio de motor de sql y del agente ahora mismo, siempre me devuelve el error "no se efectuó ninguna asignación entre los nombres de cuenta y los identificadores de seguridad", sin importar que cuenta le ponga: administrador local del equipo , administrador de dominio, o cuenta de dominio recién creada con privilegios (aunque si arranca el servicio despues)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estoy cerca de resolver el problema, aunque debo esperar al sábado para poder hacerlo. He visto este post:
https://support2.microsoft.com/es-es/help/925976/error-message-when-you-try-to-install-a-sql-server-2005-service-pack-o

Donde parece que el error puede estar en los SID asignados en las claves de registro de mssqlserver:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.X\Setup\SQLGroup

Entiendo que al haber instalado sql server sin ser DC, y posteriormente convirtiéndolo a DC, windows elimina los SID de las cuentas locales del sistema sobre las que se instaló el sql server, pero no cambia la clave de registro, que queda asociada al antigui SID. Y quizás aquí es donde produce el error "usergroupname is NULL".

Es posible que borrando dicha clave de registro y reiniciando el servidor se solucione el problema, o me recomiendan cambiar el SID de sqlgroup por la SID de un usuario del dominio con permisos de arranque de sql server??

Answer (score 0):

Definitivamente ha funcionado cambiando los SID en el registro. Como sospechaba, los SID que aparecían en el punto:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.X\Setup\SQLGroup

pertenecían a un SID que ya no existía (debido a la conversión y desconversión a DC) , al cambiarlos por el SID de mi actual administrador del dominio, me ha dejado hacer el update a 2014 y ya no me da error al cambiar de cuenta de servicio. GRACIAS